# Axler's proof of existence for the polar decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm reading Axler's proof of the existence of the polar decomposition of a linear operator, and he starts by positing the existence of a linear map, $S_1$, such that $S_1(\sqrt{T^*T}v) = Tv$ (see excerpt below).

From the excerpt, it's clear that $S_1$ exists. It's also clear that $S_1$ is norm preserving. However, what I'm struggling with is his last comment, that $S_1$ is a linear map. And as he suggests, I am dutifully trying to verify this claim.

Obviously one could construct a linear map $T(T^*T)^+$ that does the job, where $A^+$ denotes the pseudo-inverse of $A$. But this is not very elegant. How else might you construct the linear map $S_1$?

Any insights are welcomed.

---

### [image: polar decomposition proof]

Answer (score 0):

You can prove this elementary: take advantage that the domain of $S$ is the range of $\sqrt{T^*T}$, and use linearity of $\sqrt{T^*T}$.

Take $u_1,u_2\in Range(\sqrt{T^*T})$. Then $u_i = \sqrt{T^*T}v_i$ for $v_i\in V$, $i=1,2$. Now let $\lambda\in \mathbb C$. Obviously, $\lambda u_2 \in Range(\sqrt{T^*T})$, 
$$
u_1 + \lambda u_2 = \sqrt{T^*T}v_1 + \lambda \sqrt{T^*T}v_2 = \sqrt{T^*T}(v_1 + \lambda v_2).
$$
Then
$$
S(u_1 + \lambda u_2) = \sqrt{T^*T}(v_1 + \lambda v_2) = \sqrt{T^*T}v_1 + \lambda \sqrt{T^*T}v_2 = S(u_1) + \lambda S(u_2).
$$